# What illnesses/symptoms should I look for with a new cat?

Tags: cats, health, multi-pet-families

We are adopting a new (rescue) cat next weekend. The rescue that we are getting him from recommends a 7-10 day isolation period before we introduce him to our current cats to make sure that he isn't ill and doesn't transmit any illnesses to our other cats.

What illnesses and/or illness symptoms should I be on the lookout for?

Part of the recommended integration period also recommends taking bedding that smells like him and putting it where our other cats can smell it and vice versa (so they can smell each other before meeting). Should I wait to do this until after the isolation period, or a certain number of days through the isolation period to make sure that he doesn't have a skin disease?

Finally (out of curiosity), I have medical records on our new cat for the past month (his second worming is tomorrow, he's had FeL/FIV testing, etc). If this was a stray cat off the street, would the isolation period be longer/different?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, but for others doing the same. The main things to monitor in new/stray cats are appetite, vomition, lethargy, runny poops, struggling or inability to urinate and breathing and eye problems. Common diseases/conditions that hit suddenly includes Feline Herpiesvirus (eyes, mouth, lungs), Feline Corona virus (appetite, diarrhoea), stress (urination problems).

As a stray you unfortunately don't know the history and diseases like Feline Leukaemia (FeLV) and Feline Aids (FIV) is a definitely a possibility, even if they are vaccinated, but for example not tested. These diseases can take months to show clinical signs (weight loss, inappetance, lethargy, fever, other diseases, etc. etc.)